# ADB is not performing any action

Tags: android, adb

None command actions work.

- adb kill-server  -> not performs any action
- adb start-server -> not performs any action
- adb devices      -> not shows any action

I tried to follow several ways to fix the isse, but nothing seems to work. The steps are:

1. I have reinstalled the drivers, I checked the 'device manager' having:

   - Android Phone -> Android Composite ADB interface
2. I verified the phone has its 'USB debugging' options enabled (also tried with a different one).
3. Switching the phone to 'fastboot mode', then ADB recognized the phone making use of:

   - 'fastboot devices' command.
4. Reinstalling the ADB and the drivers, with ADB auto-installer:

   - ADB installer v1.3.0 -> installation finishes properly, although ADB does not work yet
   - ADB installer v1.4.5 -> installation does not finish

I do not know what more I can test to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command promt and got android sdk>platform-tools> adb kill-server

press enter

and again adb start-server

press enter

Do you do that? Kindly specify your exact problem, please.

Comment: Currently, I do not have the SDK installed. It is only installed the ADB.